# Why str(random.choice()) returns /string/

Tags: python, string, random

I am trying to make a function that randomly throws the strings of rock paper or scissors. However when I debug I notice that the variable attaching random. choice is in the following format:

[image: Output of the random.choice]

That means that the condition is never met. This the code of my function.:
*I know is not complete.*

```
def detect(player_pick):

enemy_pick = str(random.choices(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']))
# Rock detection
if enemy_pick == 'rock' and player_pick == 'scissors':
    print("you lose")
    return "rock_win_enemy"
elif enemy_pick == 'scissors' and player_pick == 'rock':
    print("Enemy lose")
    return "rock_win_player"
elif enemy_pick == 'rock' and player_pick == 'rock':
    print("tie")
    return "tie"
# Paper detection
# Scissors detection
```

Comment: [Because you're using the wrong function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)

Comment: why do you have to do `str(random.choice(...))`, just do `random.choice(...)`

Comment: The problem is that i tried like that but it's giving the value as a list not as an string. So i thought is a good idea to convert that to a string.

Comment: @AdonsFco. You're converting the list into a string instead of taking the string from the list. That's the opposite of a good idea

Comment: That being said, you're doing good for a beginner. I've been wading through incomplete "gimme teh codez" questions all day, so it's nice to see that you actually took the time to provide complete information and analyze the problem as best you could. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called `random.choices` (with an `s`) not `random.choice`. It returns a `list` of results (and oddly, doesn't require you to say how many you want; it defaults to making just one choice). As a result, `enemy_pick` is always a length 1 `list`, the `str` form of which will never be equal to any of your strings (they aren't wrapped in square brackets). Use `random.choice` (no `s`), not `random.choices`, and it should work (you can remove the `str()` wrapping too; all the choices available are already `str`).

Comment: Thanks a lot it was just a letter hahaha.

Comment: @AdonsFco: Yeah, I'm honestly confused as to why they'd give the `k` argument a default instead of making it mandatory. Seems like they *wanted* people to make this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `random.choices` which returns list.

Use `random.choice` method instead - it returns string.